# Migrating Mail from One Account to Another: imapsync or offlineimap?

Tags: linux, email, imap

I had originally asked [the original, closely-related question on superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/205504/backup-imap-email-account-to-a-hosted-google-account), but I feel this might be a little more stackoverflow speed since I want something programmatic and automated, using tools no one there knows well.  Here is the scenario:

**Two accounts:**

- Account A (original work account with
  quota)
- Account B (new backup email
  account)

**Process:**

- Create folder in Account B (e.g. "2010 Email Backup" folder).
- Migrate all folders in Account A nested into new folder on Account B (e.g. "2010 Email Backup" -> "Inbox", "Sent", "Trash", etc.).

I want to be able to do this every couple of months or every year, and script it for my needs with either imapsync or offlineimap.  So: will using these tools, if this is possible, cause an issue when it checks Account A and clears out Account B because the original folders are different?  I am not sure how specific they are, so I wanted some reports from the field.  If anyone has experience with these tools, PLEASE let me know.  I would love to figure this out before I hit a quota.

Comment: @leppie Well, I guess not.  However, I have found plenty of questions here that are not explicitly programming questions.  It might be me, but the FAQ explicitly says it is ok if it involves  [software tools commonly used by programmers or matters that are unique to the programming profession](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). But what do I know? This is not [the first time](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=imapsync) someone asked such a question. But, you did not rank me down, so I assume you have figured this out.  Thanks for pointing out the obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `imapsync` FAQ:

Q. I have moved from Braunschweig to Graz, so I would like to have my
   whole Braunschweig mail sorted into a folder `INBOX.Braunschweig` of my
   new mail account.

R.
1) First try (safe mode):

```
imapsync \
 ...
 --regextrans2 's/INBOX(.*)/INBOX.Braunschweig$1/' \
 --dry --justfolders
```

2) See if the output says everything you want `imapsync` to do, 
   `--dry` option is safe and does nothing real.

3) Remove `--dry`. 
   Check the imap folder tree on the target side.

4) Remove `--justfolders`.

Comment: Just for the morons like me who did not read the page thoroughly enough, [here is the link to the FAQ](http://www.linux-france.org/prj/imapsync/FAQ).  And it is glorious ASCII text!  You sir, are a god.  It is also really funny and ironic YOU got the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Good tip,  never realized you could use --dry or pick another folder with `--regextrans2`

Could of been possible with:

`--prefix1 INBOX.Braunschweig`

You might also want to use `--subscribe` to make sure that you don't have any folders your not subscribed to that could otherwise get missed.

We actually wrote a cPanel IMAPSYNC too.